# @After and @Before annotation is not executing second method

Tags: java, cucumber, junit4, bdd

I have declared 2 methods @after annotation but it will execute only the first method, it does not allow me to execute the second method. Please have a look at the below code

I want to execute 1 method every time for the exit of the browser.
I want to execute the second method for failed test cases.

```
@Before
public void databaseLoading(Scenario scenario) {
    //System.out.println("Test Environment Set Up");
    System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------     TEST ENVIRONMENT SET UP      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("Executing Scenario :-> " + scenario.getName());
}

@After
public void browserTearDown()
{
    System.out.println("End the browser");
    driver.close();
 }

public void Screenshot(Scenario scenario) {
    // take the screenshot at the end of every test
    String location = ".\\target\\TakeScreenshot";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = new Date();
    File scrFile =
            ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // now save the screenshto to a file some place
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(location + "\\" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".png"));
            System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in taking Screenshot --> " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Method 'Screenshot(cucumber.api.Scenario)' is never used. This error message comes for the second method.

Comment: where is your @before annotation

Comment: All methods you want to execute before or after a test have to be tagged with `@Before` or `@After`, respectively. `Screenshot(Scenario)` is not tagged, and code from your sample never calls it either. You might want to make it a `@Rule` instead either way.

Comment: Scratch the rule suggestion, cucumber might not support rules.

Comment: put TearDown method to the last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only tagged `browserTearDown()` method.

Add the `@After` tag to the `Screenshot()` method, as well:

```
@After
public void browserTearDown()
{
    System.out.println("End the browser");
    driver.close();
}

@After
public void Screenshot(Scenario scenario) {
   ...

}
```

Comment: Hi Mate, Thank you so much for your help. It is working now.